# Full Text Search StopList in SQL Server does not work

Tags: sql-server

I'am new to SQL Server and I am reading Full Text Index , I have found that a stop word in stop list is considered in subsequent searches , that is to say , it doesn't remove from the full text index.
Here is an example,
I have a table below :
[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZuI9.png)
"Id" column is a int type primary key in constraint "id_pkey",
"Name" and "description" column are both varchar(max) type,

First, I create a full text catalog named "FlatSearch":

```
create fulltext catalog FlatSearch;
```

Second, I create a full text index on column "description" in table "products":

```
create fulltext index on products(description) key index id_pkey on FlatSearch;
```

Third, I create a fulltext stoplist:

```
create fulltext stoplist ProductStopList;
```

Fourth, I associate Custom Stoplist with Full Text Index:

```
alter fulltext index on products set stoplist ProductStopList;
```

Finally, I add a stop word "develop" in custom StopList:

```
alter fulltext stoplist ProductStopList add 'develop' Language 1033;
```

Then, I use "CONTAINS" to full text search:

```
select * from products where contains(description,'develop');
```

Below is the result of full text search:
[result of full text search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9OM.png)

could anyone tell me what's going wrong ?

I expect that there is no matched result, but it came out having two row datas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your third statement has `ProductSoptList` instead of `ProductStopList`. I assume that's a typo in your question? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74584242/edit) the question if that is the case. Also, which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @Sander Thank you , I have edited the question , but that's just my typo error in this post , and I'm using SQL Server 2022. I fount that if I use the letter 'a' as a stop word in SYSTEM StopList , there is no matched result of query , just as I expect , but custom StopList won't work.

Answer (score 0):

do you not have to update or re-create the index after altering the stopword list?

If you create the index with certain parameters, you must populate the index manually, however it doesn't appear this is the case with your example. In this case, the DB will update the index with a full population update, which can take a while - it reads every row to recreate the index with the new stopword list. So trying again later might give you the correct results.

If not, try to force an update of the index:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON products START FULL POPULATION
```

should kick off a full update, or warn if its in-progress. I've never tried to add a new stopword to an existing index, so I dont know if that automatically updates every row in the index or just applies to new/updated records. Possibly the latter simply because most fulltext indexes are very big and slow to re-create with a new stopword.

Comment: Thank you , but I have found that it is automatically population and even I switch to manual population and execute the command above that you have post , result of query still exist the one that has stop word I created. Maybe most fulltext indexes are very bid and slow to create just as you have said ?